# While Migration of JBoss EAP 6 to JBoss EAP 7 facing issues in authentication of application

Tags: spring-security, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

After deployment in JBoss EAP
When I login in app my application is giving the error for session validation.

I have configured `spring security.xml` to use `'j_spring_security_check`' as login processing URL.

Comment: Are you talking about JBoss EAP 6 and JBoss EAP 7 or JBoss AS 6 and JBoss AS 7? (I know it's confusing, but they are quite different)

Comment: JBOSS EAP 6.1 to JBoss EAP 7.0 migration